# Colour of label isn't changing

Tags: python, kivy

I'm following this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032595.do and I can't seem to be able change colour of a label.

This is the code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
<WeatherApp>:
    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text: 'hey !'
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Label:
            text: 'mark !'
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Label:
            text: 'what is up ?'
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1

''')

class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What color have you set? what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the text or the background color?

Comment: I'm trying to set the colour of the text to white.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you get?Could you show a picture of what you get? Do you observe any text?

Comment: I'm getting black screen and nothing else. No need for screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the Label does not set a color, the default color of the text is white, so it is not necessary to change it.

the problem is that you are not loading the design, when you use : you are only declaring a widget, you are not using it, in addition an App is not a widget so you should not declare it in the design.

Below I show the corrected example:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'hey !'
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Label:
        text: 'mark !'
        color: 1, 0, 1, 1
    Label:
        text: 'what is up ?'
''')

class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time explaining it. It is clearer to me now. Cheers !